# Dojo 'on' event from 'byId' triggers TypeError

Tags: javascript, events, dojo, event-handling

I have a module which contains a switch statement producing content, and a variety of `on` events waiting dependent on what content is inserted into the DOM and then whichever trigger is activated.

I'm finding that `on` event handlers using `dom.byId('foo')`:

`on(dom.byId('foo'), touch.press, function(e){`

produce the error:

`Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'on' of null`.

I can kind of understand this - if the node `foo` doesn't yet exist because a different switch condition has been satisfied, but i've managed to skirt this by using a css class instead:

`on(query('.foo'), touch.press, function(e){`

But this has the same chance of existence as the `id`!

I'm relatively new to Dojo, and have had "fun" getting to grips with it, and i'm interested to know why this is happening, but also if it's a Big Red Flag that i'm doing something wrong!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without the full code but if you want to use query you need to use this way :

```
require(["dojo/query"], function(query){
  query(".foo").on("click", clickHandler);
});
```

I don't know the context of your project but if it's for mobile you maybe look at "dojo/gesture/tap" like in this exemple in the doc :

```
define(["dojo/on", "dojo/gesture/tap", function(listen, tap){
on(button, tap, tapHandler);
...
```